# using getStore on view reference does not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have defined a controller, and assigned refs in it like this:

```
refs: 
    [
        {
            ref: 'refugeDetails',
            selector: 'refugedetails'
        }
    ]
```

I have created a view with xtype = 'refugedetails', and in a function deleteAdmin in my controller I try to remove a record from the store of this view, like this

```
deleteAdmin: function(index) {
    this.getRefugeDetails().getStore().removeAt(index);
}
```

But it doesn't work, so I tried to see in the same function if getStore returns something like

```
    var st = this.getRefugeDetails().getStore();
    if(st) Ext.Msg.alert('st', 'exists');
    else Ext.Msg.alert('st', 'does not');
```

But I do not get an alert, and in the console I get "TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getStore'". Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: show how you created your custom component `refugedetails` [i.e. how you define its store, etc]

Answer (score 2):

You cant get store's object form panel.
you can use below code

```
var st = Ext.getStore('yourStoreId');
```

it will return object of store.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
     var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup("RoleStore");
```

and the 'RoleStore' is you defined

```
    Ext.define("PRO.store.role.RoleStore", {});
```